# How to extract data that loads differently with scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I’m trying to extract product reviews on URLs like this one

https://www.namastevaporizers.com/products/mighty-vaporizer

the spider I have extracts anything on the page but nothing from the comments, I think it is because the comments load differently but unfortunately this is where my knowledge of scrappy ends. Can anyone help me with this?

here is my spider

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
    from Namaste.items import NPPItem

   class NPP(Spider):
name = 'Product_Pages'
start_urls = ['https://www.namastevaporizers.com/products/mighty-vaporizer'

def parse(self, response):
    item_loader = ItemLoader(item=NPPItem(), response=response)

    item_loader.add_css("Z_reviews", "div.yotpo-user-name") # gets nothing
    item_loader.add_css("Z_reviews", "div.content-title") # gets nothing
    item_loader.add_css("Z_reviews", "div.content-review") # gets nothing
    item_loader.add_css("Z_reviews", "div.yotpo") # gets some data but missing most stuff, this is the entire yotpo content wrapper

    item_loader.add_value("AAE_source_url", response.url) #works fine

    return item_loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

the reviews in this site are loaded by JS, so you need to forge the request as your chrome do

Follow these steps you will get the result

1. open your chrome dev tool, shift to network tab, search (note: it's search instead of filter) a review content, you will the
   request (I got the request url:https://staticw2.yotpo.com/batch)
2. Copy the curl command in chrome
3. Execute the curl in shell, if it's success, the next step is parse the curl and forge it in python code (The curl actually works in this site, i tried)
4. You can parse the curl in https://curl.trillworks.com/#python